# Modify entity without tracking it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a method named GetAll() in service class which returns entities from entity framework. The method is as follows:

```
public ActionResult List()
        {
         var tasklogs = _timeLogService.GetAll()
            .Select(l=>{
                l.StartTime.Value.AddHours(1);
                return l;
            });

        return PartialView(tasklogs);

        }
```

I want to show data in the view modified as per some logic, in this example, I add one hour to the original date.

The issue is, if I refresh the page, I see the hours increasing for each page refresh i.e GetAll() method returns the last modified value, all though its not the same in database, i.e. I don't save date modification in database but GetAll returns modified dates.

I read somewhere that for this to work I need to detach entities.

So, my question is, is there a better way to do it in service layer, as I have to do it in many places. The root causue of modifying date is I save dates in UTC in db, but when I display it in views, I convert it to local timezone in controller actions.

I hope I made it clear.

Thanks

Comment: One solution is to not use EF entities directly in your view.  You should try to keep your viewmodel classes separate from your data access classes for exactly this reason.  But if you *must* do it, use `AsNoTracking`, just be *very* careful about your data.

Comment: This doesn't actually sound like a "tracking" problem though.  Your code isn't saving the updated data anywhere that I can see.  Most likely you are keeping one single instance of your `DbContext` around, which will keeping all your entities loaded, and is an anti-pattern.  You should have a new instance of the `DbContext` for every logical data operation you perform.  Which usually means one new instance per `ActionMethod`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner you were correct, I had single instance of DbContext and hence the problem. It resolved after I changed to instance per request.

Answer (score 0):

As written in my comment, issue is resolved after I changed DbContext instance creation to per request.